# Bacon.js onValue() chain

Tags: javascript, bacon.js

Why the construction like

```
$("#clickme").asEventStream('click').onValue(callback1).onValue(callback2);
```

doesn't work, but this one

```
var promise = $("#clickme").asEventStream('click');
promise.onValue(callback1);
promise.onValue(callback2);
```

works.

Doesn't the onValue method return reference to object? Is any purpose of that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `onValue` method returns a function for unsubscribing, hence is not chainable.

Comment: Thx! I couldn't figure it out from doc!